# Retrieve Guest List from Calendar issue, Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

**edited from original** I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve and report out details of calendar events repeated for each guest in a table format so that the information can be turned into a simple printed-out register of attendees for each event.

I'm getting an error about range height - my code does create a Log of each event with each guest (so I can see it compiling the information correctly) but it doesn't output that to individual rows. The error is "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 7".

My code is below. I commented it to be clear on what each bit should do:

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Get Calendar Info",
    functionName : "getCal" 

  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);

}


function getCal()
{

// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet, one row for     each guest
//
// This code retrieves events and guests between 2 dates for the specified calendar.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and also calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet).

// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

var mycal = "myemailaddress";  //this is the email address of whichever Google account is to use this
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var guestEmail = "";
var guestStatus = "";
var guestName = "";

//var startDate = Browser.inputBox("Start Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");  
//var endDate = Browser.inputBox("End Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");   
//var startDate = "September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST";
//var endDate = "September 26, 2015 23:59:59 CST";

//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 01, 2015 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 22, 2015 23:59:59 CST"));
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost
sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1 onwards - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "ID","Email","Status","Name"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,18);

range.setValues(header);
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
{
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below

    Logger.log("Event "+i+": "+events[i].getId());

    var guestList=events[i].getGuestList();   //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT 
    for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++)
    {
      guestEmail = guestList[d].getEmail();
      guestStatus = guestList[d].getGuestStatus();
      guestName = guestList[d].getName();
      Logger.log("Guest "+d+": "+guestList[d].getEmail()+", Status: "+guestList[d].getGuestStatus());

      var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getId(), guestList[d].getEmail(), guestList[d].getGuestStatus(), guestList[d].getName()]];
      Logger.log(details);

    var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,guestList.length,18);
    range.setValues(details);

// Writes the formula out to calculate number of hours, for the specific row, in column 7 to match the position of the field myformula_placeholder from above.
var cell = sheet.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

}
}
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using `Logger.log()` statement for debugging.  Is the error occurring on this line:  `var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,18);`  ? Put a `Logger.log('range: ' + range);` statement right after.  What does it show in the logs?  Right now you are "hard coding" the column length as 18.  I'd change that to `var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,details.length);` .

Comment: @SandyGood I've figured out the ((class)) error - it was because I declared details within the inner loop and then tried to set it in the outer loop.  I've used your suggestion for getRange by changing it to     var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,guestList.length,18);   
however this is throwing a new error: "correct range height, was 1 but should be 7".  This is correctly saying there are 7 guests in the event, however it is only trying to create 1 'row' for details (I think). I can't seem to get the event info to be repeated for each guest - there should be an output of 7 rows.

Comment: Sorry - the above noted error should say "INcorrect range height, was 1 but should be 7"

Comment: seems your code assumes data thst is not finding. step line by line in the debugger. we don't hsve your data.

Comment: @ZigMandel my code is picking up the data as the Log is showing everything (event title, description, location,... guest email, guest status etc) but it's only returning 1 line per event and that line includes the last guest in the event (out of however many guests there are).  My code won't output a row per guest per event.

Comment: if the code were properly formatted more people would help.

Comment: @ZigMandel what do you mean? What have I formatted wrongly?

Comment: sorry,'it might be just my phone or the mobile s.o. app but indentation is off is several areas.

Comment: @ZigMandel possibly your mobile, it looks fine on my laptop. The real code in my document however doesn't look so nice currently..!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a wonderful academic at work I have completed my code and it operates exactly as required.  Final code posted below to help others.

```
function onOpen() 
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var entries = [{
   name : "Get calendar info",
   functionName : "getCal" 
}];

sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
}


// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet, one row for each guest
//
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar including all guests included in the event.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and also calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
// 
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

function getCal()
{

// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet, one row for each guest
//
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and even calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
//
// I do re-write the spreadsheet header in Row 1 with every run, as I found it faster to delete then entire sheet content,
// change my parameters, and re-run my exports versus trying to save the header row manually...so be sure if you change
// any code, you keep the header in agreement for readability!
//
// 1. Please modify the value for mycal to be YOUR calendar email address or one visible on your MY Calendars section of your Google Calendar
// 2. Please modify the values for events to be the date/time range you want and any search parameters to find or omit calendar entires
// Note: Events can be easily filtered out/deleted once exported from the calendar
// 
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

var mycal = "YOUREMAILORCALENDARADDRESS";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);


//var startDate = Browser.inputBox("Start Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");  
//var endDate = Browser.inputBox("End Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");   
//var startDate = "September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST";
//var endDate = "September 26, 2015 23:59:59 CST";

// Optional variations on getEvents
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"));
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'word1'});
// 
// Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things Google) as part of the getEvents function:
//    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
//    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
//    {search: 'word1 word2'}        Search for events with word2 ONLY
//    {search: 'word1-word2'}        Search for events with ????
//    {search: 'word1 -word2'}       Search for events without word2
//    {search: 'word1+word2'}        Search for events with word1 AND word2
//    {search: 'word1+-word2'}       Search for events with word1 AND without word2
//
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 01, 2015 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 02, 2015 23:59:59 CST"));
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 29, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("September 29, 2015 23:59:59 CST"));

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Clear the spreadsheet content before running
sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "ID","Email","Status","Name"]]

var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,18);

range.setValues(header);
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on row 2 (row = 2) to allow for the header on row 1
var row = 2; 

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
{
    var myformula_placeholder = '';
    // Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below

    var guestList=events[i].getGuestList();   //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT 

    for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++)
    {
        var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getId(), guestList[d].getEmail(), guestList[d].getGuestStatus(), guestList[d].getName()]];

        Logger.log(details);

        var range2 = sheet.getRange(row+d,1,1,18);
        range2.setValues(details);

        var cell=sheet.getRange(row+d,7); // go to column 7 (the placeholder) of the output data
        cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))'); // calculate the number of hours of the session
        cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

    }
    row=row+d; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output

}
}
```