# Google Appscript - Export calendar entries where guestlist member has a certain string in it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to GAS & Javascript. I am using very helpful code below that I found in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791626/retrieve-guest-list-from-calendar-issue-google-apps-script-gas?rq=1#_=_) to export calendar entries to sheets.

I am trying to amend it to only export entries where its a calendar entry with address/name on the guestlist with the string "Team" in it.

I tried putting in if(guestList.indexOf("Team")>-1){... } but it does not work and returns 0 entries. Would anyone know how to do this?

```js
function onOpen() 
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var entries = [{
   name : "Get calendar info",
   functionName : "getCal" 
}];

sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
}


// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet, one row for each guest
//
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar including all guests included in the event.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and also calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
// 
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

function getCal()
{

// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet, one row for each guest
//
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and even calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
//
// I do re-write the spreadsheet header in Row 1 with every run, as I found it faster to delete then entire sheet content,
// change my parameters, and re-run my exports versus trying to save the header row manually...so be sure if you change
// any code, you keep the header in agreement for readability!
//
// 1. Please modify the value for mycal to be YOUR calendar email address or one visible on your MY Calendars section of your Google Calendar
// 2. Please modify the values for events to be the date/time range you want and any search parameters to find or omit calendar entires
// Note: Events can be easily filtered out/deleted once exported from the calendar
// 
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

var mycal = "email@domain.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);


//var startDate = Browser.inputBox("Start Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");  
//var endDate = Browser.inputBox("End Date, in format MM / DD / YYYY");   
//var startDate = "September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST";
//var endDate = "September 26, 2015 23:59:59 CST";

// Optional variations on getEvents
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"));
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'word1'});
// 
// Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things Google) as part of the getEvents function:
//    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
//    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
//    {search: 'word1 word2'}        Search for events with word2 ONLY
//    {search: 'word1-word2'}        Search for events with ????
//    {search: 'word1 -word2'}       Search for events without word2
//    {search: 'word1+word2'}        Search for events with word1 AND word2
//    {search: 'word1+-word2'}       Search for events with word1 AND without word2
//
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 01, 2015 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("October 02, 2015 23:59:59 CST"));
//var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("August 1, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("August 30, 2018 00:00:00 CS"));

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Clear the spreadsheet content before running
sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "ID","Email","Status","Name"]]

var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,18);

range.setValues(header);
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on row 2 (row = 2) to allow for the header on row 1
var row = 2; 

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) 
{
    var myformula_placeholder = '';
    // Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below

    var guestList=events[i].getGuestList();
  //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT 
 
 
  
  
    for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++)

    {
     if (guestList.indexOf("Team")>-1) {
        var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getId(), guestList[d].getEmail(), guestList[d].getGuestStatus(), guestList[d].getName()]];

        Logger.log(details);

        var range2 = sheet.getRange(row+d,1,1,18);
        range2.setValues(details);

        var cell=sheet.getRange(row+d,7); // go to column 7 (the placeholder) of the output data
        cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))'); // calculate the number of hours of the session
        cell.setNumberFormat('.00');
      }
    }
    row=row+d; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output

}
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Is this your latest script? I was not sure because there is no ``if(guestList.indexOf("Team")>-1){... }`` in your script. 2. Where is the string of "Team" included in? If it is included in "name" and "email", you can retrieve it by ``guestList[d].getName()`` and ``guestList[d].getEmail()`` in your script, respectively. 3. By the way, in your script, You are trying to retrieve the events from "September 25, 2015 00:00:00 CST" to "October 22, 2015 23:59:59 CST". If this is what you want, please ignore about this. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. No I have now updated. The previous one was from the initial post. 2. Its after  //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT  3. dates are updated in new code.